# Docker won't install

Tags: docker, installation

How do you install Docker on Windows 7?

It just throws error

I would have thought installation would be super easy on the most popular operating system... Apparently not

```
Manifest extraction failed: Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject'.
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to install [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) for Windows. If not I'm sorry.

But if so, I don't think Windows 7 has the Hyper-V feature available. I think for Windows 7 you're going to need [Docker Toolbox](https://jff--docker-docs.netlify.app/toolbox/overview/). You can found the release [here](https://github.com/docker-archive/toolbox/releases).

In [Docker Desktop Windows Requirements](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/#system-requirements) it states you need:

- Windows 11 64-bit: Home or Pro version 21H2 or higher, or Enterprise or Education version 21H2 or higher.
- Windows 10 64-bit: Home or Pro 2004 (build 19041) or higher, or Enterprise or Education 1909 (build 18363) or higher.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users.
Step 1:Download and install Wise JetSearch.
Step 2: Search this "\AppData\Roaming\Docker" on your wise JetSearch search bar.
Step 3: Right-click on any file you see, then click open folder.
Step 4: Look at your address bar on top and click Roaming. Your address bar should look like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ia3A.png
[Address to Docker files location][1]
Step 5: Delete the Docker and Docker Desktop folders.

Then you are done. Try installing Docker again.
Thank you for reading